# How can I limit or choose the rows to return in a pivot?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a set of data that shows unique dates between an action that has occurred. The items painted over in black are the unique IDs and the date/time combos underneath are the unique actions. As you can see different IDs have taken a different number of actions.

I would like to limit the number of actions (dates) that are returned per ID. For example, return only the 1st value for each ID. Then return the 1st and 2nd value for each ID. Return the 2nd and 3rd value and so on.

Using the data from the screen (the ID with 20 total actions) > Returning 1st and 2nd value means only the following would appear:

- 2018-02-11 09:29:53 +0000
- 2018-03-04 19:33:40 +0000

Is it possible to achieve this in a pivot table?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/eWMVkww.png]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with filters since the fields contain numerical values (dates).

For the 1st and 1st + 2nd, you can filter on Top "N" ("N" is selectable in the `Top 10` dialog).  For the pairs in the middle of the list, filter using the `Between` options.

If the dates are stored as text, you could add a helper column that converts the values.

Note that you would need to also include the date/time values as a data field (aggregating with `Average`, `Min`, or `Max`, assuming the date/times are unique, will yield the same values).  Format those as numbers so you can see the raw values to enter in the filter.

There is a lengthy and good tutorial here on [How to Filter Data in a Pivot Table in Excel](https://trumpexcel.com/filter-data-pivot-table-excel/).

For this kind of data, with potentially long lists of entries, doing what you want to do within the pivot table isn't particularly convenient.  Another approach would be to use formulas or VBA to display your selections using the pivot table results as source data.  That isn't trivial, so if you want to pursue that option, it would make a good next question.